# AWS Oracle RDS instance takes a lot of time to create (~2hrs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I started investigating about AWS RDS as we are considering moving our production environment to AWS and I'm creating an Oracle RDS instance using Cloud Formation. When I bring up the database stack the instance creation takes between 30min to 2 hours.

I noticed that time depends on `DBInstanceClass` the bigger the class is, bigger the time it takes. For a 30min to 45min instance creation I use this parameters:

```
MasterDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
        BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
        VPCSecurityGroups:
            - Ref: SomeSecurityGroup
        AllocatedStorage: 10
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.small
        DBInstanceIdentifier: Development-DBInstance
        DBSnapshotIdentifier: ''
        DBName: DEV
        MultiAZ: false
        Engine: oracle-se2
        LicenseModel: license-included
        MasterUsername: user
        MasterUserPassword: password
        DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref SomeSubnetGroup
        CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
```

Are those the right parameters or am I missing something?

From my point of view 30min to 2hrs is lot of time, but not sure if that's an expected amount of time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think these times are typical. I built a multi-AZ Oracle RDS instance with your parameters and it took 25 minutes to complete. The MySQL equivalent took 20 minutes. I created both using the console, not CloudFormation.

The DB Instance Events log for the Oracle DB gives a breakdown of where time is being spent, and in my case looked something like this:

```
11:00 Start DB creation
11:09 DB instance created
11:09 Start conversion to multi-AZ
11:20 End conversion to multi-AZ
11:22 Start DB backup
11:25 End DB backup
11:25 DB available
```